# Spring boot rest api single access

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I'm trying to do smth quite simple theoretically but programmatically a bit challenging.

I have rest api returning some articles and I wanna count the views on those, but I want a single access to the increase endpoint per user. Meaning if the user opens the article once, i increase the views number but then if he opens it again the same day, I don't wanna do that.

I also don't wanna create a new table in db to save the views per user, I think that's an overkill. I wanna do it on the `Spring` level.

Ofc every endpoint is protected by a token to know the user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same service.

1. Connect it to a database/table where you have an PostId and a
   counter;
2. For each response given, or @After annotation, make a ++/save;

Comment: Let me clarify, the you return a JSON object with a list of, Articles ? If so than you can`t. But if it`s one by one, than you can count them..

Comment: it's a list. I explicitly mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution may be about doing a Set with key (user token + articleId + opening date) and some logic in service (or advice/interceptor) layer to increment the counter base on data in set.

Another idea may be to set a cookie for a response with max age (expiration time) and based on cookie availability increment the counter.